# Facebook authentication, return_uri, and my local uri

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm using [facebook authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/) on my site, with the "Login with Facebook" button in my nav menu on every page. Therefore the user should be able to login via facebook and be returned to the page they were on with one click. Facebook provides the return_uri parameter, which is set to /login/facebook on my site and it handles all of the authentication against the facebook API. However, once I am done with this logic and I log the user in, I need to know what page they were on originally so I can redirect them.

I've tried passing my return_uri parameter as:

http://example.com/login/facebook?local_redir=http://example.com/users/original/page

(with everything question mark and after encoded properly of course) so when I get the response back I know what their original page was. This fails when I try to get the access token. I basically need a way to have a "pass-through" parameter to facebook, but am coming up short here.

Comment: Why is it failing when you try to get the access token? Are you using the exact same redirect_uri in the call to the auth dialog and the call to exchange the `code` for an access token?

Comment: @Igy, yes it's complaining about "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request". However, I've made sure the URLs are the same between calls. It works when I don't append the local_redir as a parameter.

Comment: I’m assuming your are using the PHP SDK for handling the login stuff etc.? If so, there’s also a session in place already – so why not store the URL to the “original page” in the session at the point where the user clicks a link/button “Login with Facebook” somewhere on your site – and then just redirect them to that page after FB login is finished using the value read from the session? That would avoid any problems with additional parameters occurring in the redirect URI suddenly, which Facebook seems to object to.

Comment: @CBroe, that would work, and in fact was my backup plan. I was trying to avoid using session though. It seems like there should be a way to do this without session, but maybe not easily.

Comment: _“It works when I don't append the local_redir as a parameter.”_ – according to some of what I’ve read Facebook can be b*tchy about GET parameters sometime. Have you tried to use a redirect URI in the form `http://example.com/login/facebook/local_redir/http://example.com/users/original/page` or something, where you pass the needed parameter as part of the URL _path_ and not as query string parameters? (Might need some server-side rewriting or else to get that working.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, you pointed me in the right direction. In addition I had to do a little base 64 encoding so facebook didn't screw up with the URL. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution that works. Apparently Facebook doesn't like GET parameters or URLs embedded within URLs (even if encoded properly). Combining CBroe's suggestion from the comments and in addition converting the URL to a base 64 string did the trick:

```
string returnUrl = Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()
                          ));
```

...and then set the return_uri parameter to:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://example.com/login/facebook/local_redir/" + returnUrl);
```

When the controller receives the request that comes back from Facebook, it just decodes the URL following local_redirect, and voila!

```
string decodedRedirectUrl = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                                        Convert.FromBase64String(
                                            local_redir
                                      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

I tried all the "change CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, set trustForwarded to true, set allowSignedRequest to false, ....."

None of that worked.

Bottom line - my return_uri I was passing in to facebook to build the auth url had upper and lower case characters in the domain name. Once the auth was completed, facebook sent the browser back to that upper/lower domain name, but in the fb code itself, when it's building the current URL to make sure it matches the return_uri parameter, it uses the built in php arrays like $_SESSION, which will only provide the lower-case version - and thus the return_uri doesn't actually match the current URL.

Solution - everywhere you have your domain name, set it to lower case.